# Trouble getting downloaded Google fonts to render

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

After using Google Font URLs for my first website, I decided to download the fonts to render them offline. I'm going through W3 Schools and CSS Tricks' pages on setting up `@font-face` in CSS, but I must not have something set up right because several fonts don't render at all, and one font does render but not at the sizes I specify in the CSS. I'm having trouble pinpointing what my problem is, so I thought I'd come here for help.

Here's my font-face chunk of CSS code. I wasn't clear if I needed separate entries for each font, and since the converter I used provided a CSS sheet with separate entries, I just pasted them all in my main sheet. Note: for the `src` lines, I did try the paths with my site's home folder name before "fonts", and that didn't seem to make a difference.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker';
    src: 'fonts/permanent_marker/PermanentMarker-Regular.woff2' format('woff2'),
        'fonts/permanent_marker/PermanentMarker-Regular.woff' format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poor Story';
    src: 'fonts/poor_story/PoorStory-Regular.woff2' format('woff2'),
        'fonts/poor_story/PoorStory-Regular.woff' format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt';
    src: 'rock_salt/RockSalt-Regular.woff2' format('woff2'),
        'fonts/rock_salt/RockSalt-Regular.woff' format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Sue Ellen Francisco';
    src: 'fonts/sue_ellen_francisco/SueEllenFrancisco.woff2' format('woff2'),
        'fonts/sue_ellen_francisco/SueEllenFrancisco.woff' format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Waiting for the Sunrise';
    src: 'fonts/waiting_for_the_sunrise/WaitingfortheSunrise.woff2' format('woff2'),
        'fonts/waiting_for_the_sunrise/WaitingfortheSunrise.woff' format('woff');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Here is one section covering styles for all my headers, followed by individual styles for each header. I'm grouping them together here for conciseness, although in the actual CSS sheet they are split up.

```
h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: 'permanent marker';
  color: #301f1a;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

h1 {
  font: 5em;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}

h2 {
  font: 2em/2.5;
}

h3 {
  font: 1.6em/2.9;
}
```

And finally, regular text.

```
p {
  font-family: 'waiting for the sunrise', 'sue ellen francisco', 'poor story'; 
  font: 1.5em;
  margin: 1.5em 4.5em;
  color: #301f1a;
}

.pagination {
  font-family: 'waiting for the sunrise', 'sue ellen francisco', 'poor story';
  font: 1.5em;
  margin: 1em 14em;
  color: #301f1a;
}

span {
  font-family: 'waiting for the sunrise', 'sue ellen francisco', 'poor story';
  font: 1.2em/1.5;
  color: #3d2b25;
  border-bottom-style: double;
}
```

At the moment, only the Permanent Marker font renders at all, but not to the sizes I specify in the different header sections, they appear small. For everything else, I just get whatever system font BBEdit defaults to as if no font is specified.

Comment: Alright, I solved my own problem. Basically, following Mozilla's guide for src parsing solved my problems: https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-fonts/#font-face-src-parsing. Basically dumb syntax errors on my part, but it's my first time saving fonts locally, so a good learning experience. I'm still not sure if I need to have separate entries for each font, or if I can condense most of them that have similar fields except for the Sunrise font. If anyone can answer that question, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to size your text you should use `font-size: 1.5rem`

The font property is a shorthand property for:

font-style
font-variant
font-weight
font-size/line-height
font-family
The font-size and font-family values are required. If one of the other values is missing, their default value are used.

in this case you only put the size: `font: 1.5em` you would need to add a font family: `font: 1.5rem 'waiting for the sunrise';`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, so I'm guessing there's something wrong elsewhere with how I have the fonts hooked up to the pages and sheets.

Comment: what you could do is just import the fonts using google fonts. i also saw in your code that your not using capital letters while you defined them with capital letters try `font-family: 'Waiting for the Sunrise', 'Sue Ellen Francisco', 'Poor Story';`

Comment: I was importing from Google Fonts previously, but I wanted to use the fonts locally instead. Your new suggestion didn't work either.

Comment: then there is something with the connection to the files but im not familiar with those issues.